# gitkraken 'refs/heads/master' is behind 'refs/remotes/origin/master'

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, gitkraken

I made a new repo and tried to commit a react.js project but I got this error "'refs/heads/master' is behind 'refs/remotes/origin/master'" and when I try to pull it says "no merge base found".
Im really new to this stuff so I dont know what im doing wrong it might be something stupid.

btw im using gitlab and gitkraken.

Comment: Are you sure you made a _new_ repo?

Comment: It seems your local master was not created from a commit that's reachable from origin/master. Try `git pull origin -r master` to update the local master.

Comment: sry for the delay but git pull origin -r master did work! thanks

Answer (score 1):

It might be because the remote repo is in protected mode and you do not right to push directly to master.

**You can try this way:**

-Create a branch in your local repo and then try to push it in the origin to remote repo.

-Then make merge request to maintainer of your repo to merge the project you created in master branch